# Convert hh:mm:ss to days (vb.net Wn App)

Tags: vb.net, time

In my vb.net code is there a way to convert it from hh:mm:ss to days format. Like if input is "05:06:07" then output should be "0.212581018518519". Basically it converts the total seconds to days.

Please suggest if .net provides me with a build-in method to achieve the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [System.TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) type.

You want to parse the string into a timespan and then look at the TotalDays property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Today);
Response.Write(ts.TotalDays);
```